# Linkedin API - how to do I comment on an existing post using PHP?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

Trying to post on a comment in Linkedin using the API.
I have OAuth up and running, I can mange to get a working token, but I use the following to comment on a post:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/comments',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "objectUrn": "urn:li:activity:<POST_ID>",
    "message": {
      "text": "This is great."
    }
  }',
  
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: text/plain'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Assuming post_id is taken from https://www.linkedin.com/posts/activity-123113456965144456-_3RW   as "123113456965144456"

The error I am getting is

{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource comments does not exist","status":404}

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me... I hope it will help you as well

```php
$comment = [
    'text' => 'Your comment text here',
];

$post_id = '{POST_ID}'; // Replace with ID of the existing post

$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{$post_id}/comments";

$access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE'; // Replace with access token for authorized user

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'x-li-format: json',
];

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($comment));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// Process response as needed
```

Comment: Tried that, im getting :   {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/This is awesome]","status":403}